# Выбрать часть строки без лишних пробельных символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строчка:

`"      Виртуальная память:       Макс. размер: 7 826 МБ      "`

Я хочу разделить её на две части по первому двоеточию. В сыром виде выражения выглядят [так](https://regex101.com/r/XKBcAl/2):

```
in: ^(.*?)\: - до первого двоеточия
out: "      Виртуальная память"
in: \:(.*?)$ - после первого двоеточия
out: "       Макс. размер: 7 826 МБ      "
```

**Вопрос: что нужно добавить, чтобы исключить лишние пробельные символы из получившихся выражений?**

ожидаемый результат: "Виртуальная память" и "Макс. размер: 7 826 МБ"

*P.S. Я использую их для разделения датафрейма:*

```py
df['параметр'] = df[0].str.extract('^(.*?)\:', expand=True)
df['значение'] = df[0].str.extract('\:(.*?)$', expand=True)
```

*поэтому делать выборку в два этапа, к примеру при помощи `re.sub(r'[\s]{2,}', '', content)` не очень актуально*

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XKBcAl/3

Comment: Уверены, что лучше использовать `re`? Может, проще будет воспользоваться `str.split(":", 1)`? В качестве параметра потом брать `[0]`, а значения `[1]` от результата.

Comment: Как??Вставил его в строчку: df[0].str.extract('^\s*(.+?)\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*$', expand=True) Так он сразу вернул искомых два столбца безо всяких дополнительных присвоений поотдельности.  Волшебство какое-то.  Буду рад, если сможете дать более расширенный комментарий..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'^\s*(.+?)\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*$'
```

В общем-то комментировать нечего, банально просто выделил группы с нужной информацией, а вокруг них добавил захват 0 и более пробельных символов.

https://regex101.com/r/XKBcAl/3

Comment: да, вроде понял.  первая группа "^\s*(.+?)\s*", вторая группа "\s*(.+?)\s*$". И разделитель между ними. Не знал, что регулярки могут возвращать условный "список". Так я, видимо, и получил два столбца.